# what is the difference between cl_datatype and usual datatype

Tags: opencl

What is the difference between cl_Type and regular Type like cl_float and float regarding the size and the usage. Can cl_float be used in kernels?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In the kernel, you have to use `float`, `int`, etc. They are standardized by the OpenCL specifications.
Because they can differ from the types used by your normal compiler, you should use the `cl_*` versions in your host code (and only there).
For example, a `cl_float` on your host is the same as a `float` in your kernel.

Comment: Thanks. but what if I use float on host?

Comment: If you use float on the host, it's not guaranteed that it has the same size as a float in the kernel. You can use float in the host, but you should make sure they have the same size, or cast to cl_float when reading from or writing to the device.